# Что должно произойти при повторном освобождении памяти?

Tags: c, c++

```
/* C */
int *p = (int *)malloc(size);

free(p);
free(p);

// C++
int *p = new int[size];

delete[] p;
delete[] p;
```

Код должен заведомо упасть или это зависит от компилятора?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Undefined behavior. Может и не упасть. 
Компилятор мало погоды тут делает.

Comment: В режиме отладки, скорее всего, будет какая-нибудь внятная ошибка. В релизе — ждите чего угодно :). Конечно же, это зависит от компилятора\среды. Но в любом случае так делать нельзя.

Comment: Я бы сказал от среды выполенения - в смысле Windows (какой именно), Unix (какой именно). Все они по-разному реагируют на плохое обращение с кучей.

Comment: Почти наверняка упадет 
(особенно если между free() есть malloc()), 
к сожалению, обычно падает не сразу на втором free(),
а где-то на следующих malloc().

Comment: "Почти наверняка упадет (особенно если между free() есть malloc()), к сожалению, обычно падает не сразу на втором free(), а где-то на следующих malloc()." ага - именно на втором alloc.

Comment: Что бы не падало, можно воспользоваться тем, что delete 0 это валидная конструкция.

delete[] p; p = 0;
delete[] p; p = 0;

Скомпиленный с помощью mingw пример ошибок не выдает( ни в release, ни в debug).

Comment: Было бы удивительно, если бы падало хоть в release, хоть в debug :). Стандарт гарантирует, что удаление нулевого указателя — безопасная операция.

Comment: однакко тем не менее падает проверено на gcc version 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8)

Comment: тут указатель не нулевой.

Answer (score 0):

Сишный - упадет почти наверняка. Потому что malloc при выделении памяти записывает служебную информацию в начало выделенного блока, а затем free эту информацию использует.

С++ код грохнется тоже, но мне кажется, что он может выкинуть исключение, а еще лучше запихать все в блоки try-catch :-)

А еще лучше лучше следовать соглашению - все пойнтеры инициализировать NULL и когда они удаляются тоже делать их NULL, т.е.:

```
int *ptr = NULL;
...
ptr = (int*)malloc(size); // приведением затыкаем рот компилятору
if (ptr == NULL)
{
  // ошибка! сделайте что-нибудь.
}
...
if (ptr!=NULL)
{
  free(ptr) //иначе ptr уже убит и делать ничего не надо
  ptr = NULL;
}
...
// закончили работу программы
```

Comment: try..catch скорее всего тоже не поможет. так же перед удалением (во всяк случае delete'ом) нет смысла проверять указатель на null. У некоторых эти проверки превращаются в паталогическую привычку, и потом весь код ими пестрит. по мере возможности лучше испольховать "умные" указатели

Comment: Умные указатели - да, хорошая идея. Используя C++ используйте STL и Boost? :-)
<i>так же перед удалением (во всяк случае delete'ом) нет смысла проверять указатель на null.</i>
<pre>delete p;
p = NULL;
delete p;</pre>
не валится на втором delete
<pre>delete p;
delete p;</pre>
валится :-(

Comment: вот это лишино смысла:
if (ptr!=NULL)
{
  delete ptr;
  ptr = NULL;
}

Comment: А я и не говорил обратного :-)
try/catch по ходу не работают